# How to do header authentication using NuSOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am using NuSOAP to create a soap API but now I want to the authentication using headers in NuSOAP. I don't want to create any authentication function for that. Please guide me how can I do this using headers?

I have gone through this example:
[how to authenticate Soap Header in nusoap server in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629731/how-to-authenticate-soap-header-in-nusoap-server-in-php). My problem is that I am not able to understand how to get the header on server side.

Comment: Can you show us any code you have so far, any research, or some information relating to your SOAP service as it stands? Currently this is rather brief, and we could do with a bit more detail.

Comment: I have searched but it is showing to create a new function.

Comment: OK, so you went through that example. What are you getting stuck on? Did you actually run the code?

Comment: I am worried how do i get the header on server side?

Comment: I am not able to understand how do i get the header on server side?@halfer

Comment: In PHP, server headers are usually exposed via `$_SERVER`, but there may be something else in NuSOAP. I don't know NuSOAP at all, just trying to get your question into an answerable shape for someone who does. Have you actually got some working SOAP PHP code?

Comment: Now i don't have requirement of sending parm as header  now i am trying to send it as part of soap body